# Doxygen does not document my non-class functions in PHP?

Tags: php, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen (Doxywizard the GUI) to document a PHP project. Doxygen is not documenting my non-class files.

i.e. In some files, I havenot created any class, the file just contains some functions. Doxygen is not documenting the functions. Any help?

Here goes the [config file](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/404) Doxywizard generated for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you put a comment block containing a @file command in the file?

See also http://www.doxygen.org/docblocks.html#structuralcommands
(the paragraph that starts with "Let's repeat that, because it is often overlooked")

Comment: FWIW I found if you want to document each function in a non-class type php file, just add @file at the start of each comment block then comment as you would normally.